# Can't use Data Explorer as a sink in Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do a Data Flow using ADL1 as the source and Data Explorer as the sink; I can create the source but when I select Dataset for Sink Type the only available options in the Dataset pulldown are my ADL1 Datasets. If I use Data Copy instead I can choose Data Explorer as a sink but this won't work as Data Copy won't allow null values into Data Explorer number data types. Any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Data Explorer connector is not supported in Data flow as source and sink.

Comment: Suggestion is that you could use notebook or function to deal with the null values in ADL1 and then import the data into Data Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. First I Data Copy the csv file into a staging table where all columns are strings. Then I Data Copy from staging table to production table using a KQL query that converts strings to their destination data types.